# Approximating $4$th order order polynomial by $3$rd order polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Let us assume that we have the following polynomial for complex $\omega$.

$$ \omega ^4+c_3\omega^3+c_2\omega^2+c_1\omega+c_0=0$$

Is there some rigorous criterion under which it can be approximated as the following?

$$ c_3\omega^3+c_2\omega^2+c_1\omega+c_0=0 $$

For example, maybe if $|\omega|\ll 1/|c_3|$? If that is possible, what happens to the fourth root of the equation?